# jQuery .attr() method returning undefined

Tags: jquery, undefined, attr

```
<ul id="footernav">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="chat" data-icon="custom" data-transition="none">Tools</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="email" data-icon="custom" data-transition="none">My Ride</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="login" data-icon="custom" data-transition="none">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="skull" data-icon="custom" data-transition="none">Cool</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="coffee" data-icon="custom" data-transition="none" class"ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now I am using this jQuery function to get the `id` of the `li` which I have clicked:

```
$('#footernav li').click(function(){                     
    alert($(this).attr('id'));                    
});
```

But it returns `undefined`.

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/k4Mcy/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's because your `li` don't have IDs

Use this selector instead: `$('#footernav li a')`

Answer (score 6):

Because you are on the li element not on the a tag.

You should listen to

```
$('#footernav li a').click(function(){
     alert($(this).attr('id'));

});
```

Answer (score 5):

This will help you out

```
$('#footernav li').click(function(){                     
     alert($('a',this).attr('id'));                    
});
```